# Getting suggestion to use Java 8 library for Java 11 project inside Android Studio. Why?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Inside build.gradle:

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
```

Code:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycleVersion"
```

Which line suggestion is coming:

```
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycleVersion"
```

What suggestion is coming in yellow color:

> Use the lifecycle Java 8 API provided by the 'lifecycle-common-java8'
> library instead of Lifecycle anotations for faster incremental build.

Troubleshooting:

1. Inside AS preference - Build tools - Gradle version is 11
2. In build.gradle file also manually set from Java 1.8 to 11
3. To check whether it is happening in my actual project only or not, I created demo project, but there also same suggestion getting
4. Tried with Invalidate caches and restart
5. Using latest stable version of Android Studio

I'm not getting suggestion if I use below, but the question is why should I use Java 8 thing in Java 11 project?

```
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycleVersion"
```

Comment: I'm just guessing, but this could mean that `lifecycle-compiler` is for Java 7, while `lifecycle-common-java8` adds support for Java 8 and higher, which means it is also for Java 11 (but, I don't do Android, so I'm just guessing).

Answer (score 1):

That Jetpack library is for Java 8 **and up**. It uses an interface with default method implementations instead of an annotation processor (which slows down compile time) for subscribing to Lifecycles. Java 7 didn't support default implementations for abstract methods. When a Jetpack library has a Java version in the name, that's a minimum version required, not a maximum version recommended.

Since you are using a Java version **higher** than 7, it is recommending that you use that more performant library.

Comment: Did you my question? I want to use Java 11

Comment: Read the answer more carefully. If you are using Java 11, you are using a version of Java higher than Java 7, so you *should* be using this Jetpack library that requires at least Java 8. “java8” in the name of the library means it requires at least Java 8, which is of course true if you are using Java 11.